# XCode - Writing static analysis friendly code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm starting to make use of static code analysis to find memory management problems in my code.  I've found it very useful, but there are a couple of bits of code I've written that I'm sure aren't causing memory leaks (instruments doesn't report any) but are being reported by the analyser.  I think it's a question of me writing the code in a non-friendly manner.  Here's an example

```
for (glyphUnit *ellipsisDot in ellipsisArray) {
    CGPathRef newDot = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(ellipsisDot.glyphPath, &ellipsisTransform);
    CGPathRelease(ellipsisDot.glyphPath);  // Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller
    ellipsisDot.glyphPath = newDot;
}
```

where `glyphUnit` is a simple custom class that has a `GCPathRef` as a property, which the custom class releases in its `dealloc` method.  So in this loop I'm transforming the path and storing it in a`newDot` then releasing the original glyphPath so I can assign the newly created one to it.  I can see how this is getting the code analyser confused, with it giving a  message I'm decrementing an object I don't own. Is there another way swap in the new path without confusing it?

Answer (score 3):

It should be,

```
for (glyphUnit *ellipsisDot in ellipsisArray) {
    CGPathRef newDot = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(ellipsisDot.glyphPath, &ellipsisTransform);
    ellipsisDot.glyphPath = newDot;
    CGPathRelease(newDot); 
}
```

You are creating `newDot` by doing CG CreateCopy operation and you need to do release on that variable. So the analyser is warning that you dont own `ellipsisDot.glyphPath` param to release it. You are trying to release the wrong param here. When you put that release statement in the second line as in question, `ellipsisDot.glyphPath` and `newDot` are pointing to two separate instances. Only on the third line, you were assigning `newDot` to `ellipsisDot.glyphPath`.

Comment: This code is right, but only if the `glyphUnit` class does the correct memory management in it’s `setGlyphPath:` accessor method. If the `glyphPath` property is declared as `assign` (which I assume because the code apparently is working) this code would work OK.

Comment: I am not sure about that since he is using `CGPathRelease(ellipsisDot.glyphPath);` before the third line.

Comment: @Sven you are correct, I was using `assign so it was working and I didn't have an appropriate setter method.  Using ARC in the object world had made me forget about accessor methods.  @ACB thanks for your response, I'll add an answer summarising my mistake.

Comment: @user524261, So didnt the above answer fix it? Ideally your issue in question should be fixed after this change. And you need to modify the assign statements wherever required.

Comment: @ACB, this change on its own causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS because I'd negated to add an appropriate setter.  Thanks and +1 for steering me along the right path though.

Comment: In that case if it was helpful, could you please accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I forgot about defining setters in my custom `glyphUnit` class.  Being in the ARC world for objects and used to synthesizing my methods I had forgotten the need to manage my retain counts for core foundation references.  I had been releasing glyphPath in my `dealloc`, but was not using a setter method. As @Sven suspected, I was simply using a synthesized `assign` and making up for my lack of setter method by doing some less than intuitive releases in my code snippet above.  I've now added a setter method as below to `glyphUnit`

```
- (void)setGlyphPath:(CGPathRef)newPath
{
    if (_glyphPath != newPath)
    {
        CGPathRelease(_glyphPath);
        _glyphPath = CGPathRetain(newPath);
    }
}
```

After adding this, I now had the necessary retain in place to change my code snippet to the one @ACB described and my code ran nicely (without it, it obviously caused an EXC_BAD_ACCESS).

Kudos to @Sven for inferring my mistake and setting me in the right direction... no pun intended.